# Modelling Entity Relationships in a Google Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking for some tips and tricks to Modelling Entity Relationships in a  Google Datastore. I've read this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling and the other google documentation. I'm looking for a "datastore for the relational developer" (like Java for C# Programmers) and maybe a Pubs DB like thing for datastore to poke at it with. The https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/ have a lot of info in them but I'm still having trouble visualizing how it all works.

Having all these questions about datastore makes using Search appealing. It seams a lot more simple to use and you get full text search. I've read that you should use a hybrid system but if you the 10000 result limit doesn't bother you then is it workable? Is the Eventual constancy really that slow? What is the upper and lower limit on how long it takes to propagate change?